# C# console application - Change taskbar and start menu icon

Tags: c#, icons, console-application, taskbar, startmenu

I have C# console application, whose icon associated with its exe I have changed by setting the icon value in the project properties.

However, that does not change the icon displayed in the task bar and the start menu shortcut. How do I change them ?

Comment: Set it on the forms too

Comment: Google "reset shell icon cache".